# NetTopologySuite Coordinate vs Point for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nettopologysuite

So after reading this article [Working effectively with coordinates in Entity Framework](https://medium.com/how-tos/working-effectively-with-coordinates-in-entity-framework-7ef5d0a6f06d) the author advices to use `NetTopologySuites` `Point` class for storing coordinates in the lat/lng SRID 4326 format. In that way you can request the database for spatial aware information. Cool.

But the `NetTopologySuite` also contains a `Coordinate` class. Why shouldn't I use the `Coordinate` class? Or better said, whats the difference between `Point` and `Coordinate`

Answer (score 2):

`Point` is the full fledged `Geometry` as defined in the OGC Simple Feature Specification. It can interact with other `Geometry` classes like `LineString`, `Polygon` and their `Multi` variants.

`Coordinate` is a data type for storing or creating vertices that are used in `Geometry` classes.